# Unable to resolve dependency error after updating React version

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I’m trying to upgrade to Docusaurus v3, and updating to React 18 is part of the process. I updated React, but when I then run npm update to get the latest versions for the other dependencies, I get this error that I don’t understand. Is the root project not updated when I ran npm install react react-dom in the top level directory?

It's cut off at the bottom in the image, but when I check the version of React it shows 18.2.0.
[image]